# Virtual Class C++ and Inheritance

Tags: c++, object, virtual, shapes

## Why i can't create an object from Rectangle?

I know that:

```
Shape *p;
p = new Rectangle(10,5);
```

will work but I don't understand why I can't create like the following:

```
Shape *p;
Rectangle rec;  
p = &rec;

p->shapeName();
```

The error I get is this:

> no matching function for call to 'Rectangle::Rectangle()'

Here is my minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
protected:
    double area, perimeter;

public:
    virtual void shapeName() = 0;
    virtual void shapeArea() = 0;
    virtual void shapePerimeter() = 0;

    double getArea()
    {
        return area;
    }

    double getPerimeter()
    {
        return perimeter;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
    double height, width;

public:
    Rectangle(double height, double width)
        : height(height)
        , width(width)
    {
    }

    void shapeName()
    {
        cout << "Rectangle" << endl;
    }
    void shapeArea()
    {
        area = height * width;
    }
    void shapePerimeter()
    {
        perimeter = 2 * (height + width);
    }
};

int main()
{

    Shape* p;
    Rectangle rec;
    p = &rec;

    p->shapeName();
}
```

Comment: """""Why i can't create an object from Rectangle?"""""

Comment: That's your question. How do you know you can't do it? What error do you get (if any)?

Comment: The point is you should have copied and pasted the exact text of the error message that the compiler gave you. This is a requirement for having a good question to help readers years from now.

Comment: [Error] no matching function for call to 'Rectangle::Rectangle()'

Answer (score 5):

You miss rectangle parameters:

```
Rectangle rec(10, 5);  
Shape *p = &rec;

p->shapeName();
```

in the same way

```
p = new Rectangle(); // Won't work: No default constructor.
```